# Angular - How can I specify a different node.js version than what is installed on the system?

Tags: node.js, angular, configuration, centos

System: CENTOS7

I'm working on our TEST system that has a version of node prior to 8.9.

The application which I'm working on uses node 8.9.

The application runs fine when deployed out to Tomcat.

The issue is that I'm unable to just run '`ng serve`' because the system sees v6.x.x.

Is there a way that I can modify my project to see the packaged node v8.x so I can run the ***ng options***?

> ***I'm instructed to not modify the system settings.***

---

UPDATE
Just so others know what I ended up doing was modifying my bash script to include in the PATH ./node_modules to where node was in the local project. This is always the same path for whatever project and its version on node.

I did that for a while until a few months ago when we finally had rights to do things differently and are now using Node Version Manager

Comment: Can you run `ng version` and include the output here? So we can see the version of  Node and the Angular CLI.

Comment: @frosty No. Running ng -v ends up with the message of 'You are running version v6.x of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6. The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install nvm (node version manager) to centOS
Then you will can install many version of node in your system

In this case you have to alias default version of node in nvm setting with version you want

Comment: nvm run 12.0.0 ng serve gives "Error: Cannot find module 'ng'"